# How to fix my MVC3 routing 

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, global-asax

I have some problem with routing in my ASP.NET MVC3 application, exactly it doesn't works as I want.

**Routing definition in Global.asax**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "News", // Route name
            "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{page}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { lang = "pl", controller = "News", action = "Index", page = 1, id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

So I want use it in 2 situation:

1. `/{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{page}` - to go to specific paginations' page
2. `/{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{page}/{id}` - to remember a current page, and go to page with specific `id`.

to generate **links** I use:

```
@Html.RouteLink(i.ToString(), "News", new { lang = ViewBag.Lang, page = i })
```

where `i` is number of page, and lang is language.

In **Controller** i handle it witch **Action**:

```
public ViewResult Index(string lang, int page = 1)
```

**PROBLEM**

`@Html.RouteLink` gives me link `/pl/News/Index/2` (when '2' was clicked) but my controller doesn't handle it and page is still '1'. So when I click the same link twice it gives : `/pl/News/Index/2/2` and then page equals '2'.

If somebody can explain me how it exactly works, and what can I do to solve it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's some wicked route, but what I don't see in your controller is the `id` (which is optional), shouldn't it be `Index(string lang, int? id, int page = 1)`? :)

Comment: You don't read carefully :) In index action I don't use `id` parameter, I need it only on other Action.

Comment: If I understand properly, you click `/pl/News/Index/2`, it fires the right _Index_ action, but the value of _page_ within this action is 1 instead of 2. Aren't there another routes that can match this link?

Comment: I think if I use `@Html.RouteLink` and give route name, it should take the specific one. But if url doesn't fit to rule... it take default. Hmmm I think it's the point but, I don't know why it's happen and how change it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you're missing here is that the routing system uses the variable values from the current request to generate the outbound rules.

For example - if you're on the page /pl/News/Index/2 you have

```
lang = "pl", controller = "News", action = "Index", page = 2
```

if you try to generate a rule like this

```
@Html.RouteLink(i.ToString(), "News")
```

the routing system will use the already present variables like *lang* and *page* and will generate exactly the same URL - /pl/News/Index/2.

Of course values that you pass in the anonymous type in Html.RouteLink are treated with priority and will override values from the current request. So in your example you should consider **what URL are you at when you generate the link**.

Order of precedence is:

1. variables passed in the anonymous type
2. request variables
3. default values defined in the route.

It seems that this part

```
lang = ViewBag.Lang
```

is useless since *lang* will be taken from the request if you don't supply it - so it will be preserved.

**Update**(might not be relevant):

You should also keep in mind that if you have more than one match for a rule - the routing system will choose the **first** one which satisfies the constraints(for example values from request should not conflicts with default variables)

**Update2**:

The routing system uses request variables up to the first explicitly specified variable(via the anonymous type) so if you specify *lang* explicitly - no request variables will be reused(in your case, because *lang* is the first segment in your url)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm not sure if I understand you. Do you suggest me to change sth? Also when I use `@Html.RouteLink` and give specific route name it is taking correct rule, isn't it? But I see that it doesn't overwrite `page` value. But what I must do to, it do this?

Comment: @MateuszRogulski - yes when you use RouteLink it uses the specified rule(that's why I mention my update is not relevant to your case). Could you post the whole code(all rules, all actions and the complete view) - I just tried your rule with a new MVC project and it works fine(the page value is overriden)

Comment: It take wrong route rule. But in this case I don't know how works `@Html.RouteLink`, becouse it get 'Default' route. But I solve it by change my route rules. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your problem is that you're breaking convention a bit, and since MVC relies on convention to route successfully, your mapping is a bit busted.

I would suggest rewriting your routing like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "News", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{lang}/{id}/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "News", action = "Index", lang = "pl", page = 1, id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

It seems like the most common case scenario for a URL would be something like:

```
http://yourdomainhere/news/pl/some-sort-of-permalink/1
```